# Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/lifecycle/LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver;

Tags: java, android

when run app it show error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> >     dex

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.6.2') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    compile 'com.github.TheBrownArrow:PermissionManager:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:1.0.12'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.seatgeek:placesautocomplete:0.3-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Set *all* of the `com.android.support` dependencies to `27.1.0`. As you do that, remove all of the duplicates, as you are asking for `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`, `com.android.support:cardview-v7`, and `com.android.support:design` twice.

Comment: use multidex. search for it.

Comment: i aleady use it     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

Comment: remove all duplicate dependences including firebase and support files

Comment: @Rahul That's a workaround, not an legitimate solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the same version for all support dependencies and don't add duplicate dependencies. You need to group the dependencies to make it easier to manage. Your dependencies should be something like this:

```
dependencies {

    // Support library
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

    // Firebase and Play service library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.2'

    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    implementation 'com.github.TheBrownArrow:PermissionManager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedbottompicker:1.0.12'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.seatgeek:placesautocomplete:0.3-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.7.1, 3.99.99]'

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it easier to manage, you should add an `ext` block with version variables

Comment: I definitely agree with you!